# Building a web multiplayer game in FLEX and Java

Tags: java, apache-flex

I'm building a Facebook multiplayer game where the client side is in FLEX and the server side is in Java and I wanted to know if there is a guide on how to build the server clients managing system.
When I say server clients managing system, I mean a server which many clients will connect to and will be able to choose between tables to join and play or to create their own table, same way as in texas holdem poker.
Is there something already built? is there a guide on how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might take a look at http://www.reddwarfserver.org/